# What operator is this?

Tags: operators

I was looking at some sample code in a YouTube video and saw an "operator" (not sure this is the right term) consisting of a horizontal bar with circles on the ends.  I searched through the Wolfram docs and have not been able to find it.

[image]

Can someone enlighten me?

Comment: Try: `g = Table[RandomInteger[5] \[UndirectedEdge] RandomInteger[5], {7}]` and `Graph[g, VertexLabels -> "Name"]`

Comment: Btw., you can simply highlight any symbol and press F1 to get directly to the documentation page of that symbol.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher I don't think that works on YouTube

Comment: Ahaha. Yes, you're right! Should have read the post in more detail. =D

Answer (score 10):

It's `StandardForm` of `UndirectedEdge`. It's also mentioned in e.g. document of `Graph`.

Comment: Worth adding: you can enter this symbol by typing Esc ue Esc (and Esc de Esc for directed edge).